# PhpSpreadSheet : border thickness

Tags: border, phpspreadsheet, thickness

I generate a sheet with PhpSpreadSheet. I use BORDER_THIN which makes 1,00 pt borders.
Is it a way to get 0,5 pt borders ?

Comment: Hi, BORDER_HAIR matches, thank you.

Comment: Hi Zakolis! Looks like you've found the answer to your own question. That's great! However, you've posted it as a comment, which makes it hard to find and prevents you from accepting it as the answer. Instead, please post your answer in the answer box below. Then, after a short waiting period, you'll be able to [accept it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

so BORDER_HAIR makes 0,5 pt borders !

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the border on tcpdf PDF there is a problem in the pdf print library.

Look to this github thread https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1164